# How to connect to Matlab through Java using matlabcontrol

Tags: java, matlab

I need to connect to Matlab from Java using matlabcontrol.

I tried their demos and those are working fine but when I tried to connect to Matlab using a servlet I get this error (to be clear, my code succeeds in opening an instance of Matlab but afterwards the following appears in the Matlab window):

??? Undefined variable "matlabcontrol" or class "matlabcontrol.MatlabClassLoaderHelper.configureClassLoading".

And this appears in the eclipse server window:

matlabcontrol.MatlabConnectionException: MATLAB proxy could not be created in 180000 milliseconds

I saw that this exact same question was asked by someone on stack overflow but the question had been removed, I don't know why.

I tried searching for the answer and this came up: http://code.google.com/p/matlabcontrol/wiki/Compatibility

They say here that if this error comes, to run this command in Matab: java.lang.System.getProperty('java.class.version')

And if the answer is 50 or greater then matlabcontrol should work, but it doesn't for me.

I can't understand what's wrong (demo works, my code doesn't) and I'm desperately in need of an answer. This is for a project due soon and I would appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: Which matlab version and which OS are you using?

Comment: Matlab2010a and Windows 7

Comment: Just to confirm: You don't call anything with the name of `matlabcontrol` after opening matlab right? Not sure whether the servlet is relevant, but if you can get examples working I would recommend just building on those. Otherwise consider presenting a reproducible problem here or filing a bug report with mathworks, they are probably your best bet.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestions, I did it a different way, by calling Matlab from the command prompt. This didn't work for me.